# Search a character and/or a regular expression with fgets

Tags: c, regex, fgets

I have this simple block of code who reads a line in a file with fgets().
Now I want to search in this line if there is a "{" or a "}" and put an ignore comment on the commented ones. For the functions { and } I want to add a comment like this //This is a good { . How could I manage to do that ? Should I use regex ? I removed the while loop to simplify the line by line iteration.

Can I somehow use mystring, wich I think is an array ? Can I append mystring of modify it ? Or what I have to do is to make a new array, put mystring in it and then after put the comments.

For example : myfile.txt

```
/* Hello {} */
function
{
  hello();
}
```

Output

```
/* Hello {} */ //Ignored
function
{ //This is a good {
  hello();
} //This is a good }
```

My simple block :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char mystring [100];

    pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
    else {
        if ( fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile) != NULL )
            puts (mystring);
        fclose (pFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple approach, how you could process your mystring.

```
char *ptr=strchr(mystring,'{');
if(ptr)
{  
   sprintf(mystring,"%s //This is a goof {",mystring);
}
else
{
  ptr=strchr(mystring,'}');
  if(ptr)
  {
     sprintf(mystring,"%s //This is a goof }",mystring);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know why if I put : char *ptr=strchr(str,'{\0'); it detects all the line break for every line in my file ? I wanted to be clever so I said just detect the { followed by an end of line, so the one in the comment shall be ignored ?

Comment: strchr looks up only one character in the given string. To search from the end of the string, you could use strrchr. These functions return the first occurence of the character in the given string. Using pointer arithmetic, you can find if its last-est character in the string or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be of use  http://www.lemoda.net/c/unix-regex/index.html.

I may be able to give the code ..